# Call a user control from other user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

So basically I have two User Control
1.Maptab.cs
2.TransactionTab.cs
And a Main menu. 
So I have a button in main menu and when click it calls the maptab.cs, and in maptab.cs I have a button named btnbuy. So what I want to do is to call the transactiontab.cs or bring to front in the main menu when the button btnbuy in the maptab.cs is clicked.
I tried it like this in maptab.cs:

```
    private void btnBuy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Mainmenu main = new Mainmenu();
        main.transactionTab1.BringToFront();
    }
```

and it was not working. And also I'm gonna pass some values from maptab to transactiontab.

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that you have an existing instance of `Mainmenu` somewhere, totally unrelated to the temporary one that you're calling `BringToFront()` on and discarding? If that's the case, you need to call `BringToFront()` on the real one, instead of messing with a temp that nobody can see anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After creating an instance of form, just use Show() or ShowDialog() to display your desired form.

For example,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 secondform = new Form2();
    secondform.value = 33; //"value" variable must be declared as public in Form2 
    secondform.Show(); //Use secondform.ShowDialog(); to prevent user from entering main form without closing Form2.
}
```